# Error in Ansible when modify list items with backslash

Tags: list, ansible, backslash

I have a list in following format and need to replace commas with backlash but getting error when trying to use replace function.

`"sub_keys": [
            ",,ps1,printer1",
            ",,ps1,printer2",
            ",,ps2,printer1"]
expected result:
new_list:[ "\\ps1\printer1",
"\\ps1\printer2"
"\\ps2\printer1"]`

i tried the following code:

`- name: Convert list
    set_fact:
      new_list: '{{ new_list + [item.replace (",","\")] }}'
    with_items: "{{ sub_keys }}"`

Comment: you are probably getting an error as you have only used a single backslash and have not escaped it. In here `'{{ new_list + [item.replace (",","\")] }}'` your backslash is used to keep the double quote as it is, and hence a mismatch of quotes fails your code.

Comment: hi, i tried to use \\ in replace argument. i dont get error but what i get is this
 `"new_list": [
"\\\\\\\\ps1\\\\printer1",
        "\\\\\\\\ps1\\\\printer2"]`

which doesnt seem to be OK either -

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried:

```
- name: Convert list
  set_facts:
    new_list:
      - "\\\\ps1\\printer1"
      - "\\\\ps1\\printer2"
      - "\\\\ps2\\printer1"
```

Comment: thanks for tip - problem is that i need to use the loop with vars